# Doesnt my silverlight app do pages?

Tags: silverlight

I've created a Silverlight application, and I see that it has created MainPage.xaml for me. However, this is a `UserControl`.

So I went ahead, thinking I could create a regular page, changed App.xaml.cs to set `this.RootVisual = new MyNewMainPage()`;

MyNewMainPage is a `SilverlightPage`, inherits `Page`. However, when I fire this application up, it throws the following exception in `InitializeComponent()` in `MyNewMainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.UIElement.Tap'. [Line: 10 Position: 35]
```

On line 10 I have:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Tap="LayoutRoot_Tap">
```

And the method is created in the code behind. Why is this. The reason for using pages instead of UserControl is that I want some navigation, and have several pages.

Answer (score 0):

On your mainPage you add a `Frame`, here the pages are hosted. The [UriMapper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=urimapper&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.navigation.urimapper%28v%3Dvs.95%29.aspx&ei=208FUtqBMeOiyAGUn4HABg&usg=AFQjCNFRoJqt05QKYW0vG5tLn7zvHl-rZw&bvm=bv.50500085,d.aWc) is how you navigate the pages.

```
 <navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Source="/Home" Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated" NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed" Width="Auto" Height="755" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MaxWidth="Infinity" MaxHeight="755" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
    <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
      <uriMapper:UriMapper>
         <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/Home" MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml"/>
      </uriMapper:UriMapper>
    </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
 </navigation:Frame>
```